# WCF Error:101 Page is not available

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-rest

I have this problem on WCF Rest service. When the data gets bigger like more than 1.2MB it will give me a "Error:101 This webpage is not available" in chrome. In firefox its "The connection was reset". However, it will work on small data. The data is just a plain JSON by the way.

Below is my configuration:

**WebConfig(Binding Configuration):**

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig" 
        closeTimeout="00:30:00" 
        openTimeout="00:30:00" 
        receiveTimeout="Infinite" 
        sendTimeout="00:30:00" 
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
        maxBufferSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="2147483647" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483646" 
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webclientHttpBindingConfig" 
        closeTimeout="00:30:00" 
        openTimeout="00:30:00" 
        receiveTimeout="Infinite" 
        sendTimeout="00:30:00" 
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
        maxBufferSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="2147483647" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483646" 
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

**AppConfig(Binding Configuration):**

```
   <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBindingForBigArrays" 
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
        messageEncoding="Mtom">
      <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="2147483647" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>

  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBindingConfig"
        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
      <readerQuotas 
        maxDepth="2147483647" 
        maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
        maxArrayLength="2147483646" 
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

I've been struggling on this for hours now. Your thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you are running IIS, you need to make sure that max HTTP post size is set:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" />
```

8MG is the default but your case could be set at 1MB. For info look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Is this supposed to be placed on the client only?

Comment: I have it on the client/web.config:"<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" />"

Comment: I am not sure what you meant but I placed it already on my web.config and my app.config just to make sure. That web.config is that one that is hosted on IIS. -=Still not working=- I still have the same error.